# Correlation of every pandas row with another pandas dataframe as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following `df`:

```
Company   Apples   Mangoes   Oranges

Amazon       0.75      0.6     0.98
BellTM       0.23      0.75    0.14
Cadbury      0.4       0.44    0.86
```

and then another data frame called `vendor`:

```
Company   Apples   Mangoes   Oranges

Deere       0.11      0.3     0.79
```

I want to find the row-wise correlation of each company with the company `Deere` in the `vendor` data frame. I want the outputted correlation coefficient added as a column called Correlationcoef to the original data frame df:

```
Company   Apples   Mangoes   Oranges     Corrcoef

Amazon       0.75      0.6     0.98     0.77955981 
BellTM       0.23      0.75    0.14    -0.37694478
Cadbury      0.4       0.44    0.86     0.98092707
```

When I attempt the following:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].corrwith(vendor.iloc[:,1:], axis=1)
```

I get a list with NaN values.
I obtained the Corrcoef values manually by saving each row as an array and using `np.corrcoef(x1,y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Series in corrwith.

You can use:

```
df.set_index('Company').corrwith(vendor.set_index('Company').loc['Deere'], axis=1)
```

output:

```
Company
Amazon     0.779560
BellTM    -0.376945
Cadbury    0.980927
dtype: float64
```

With your code:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].corrwith(vendor.iloc[0,1:].astype(float), axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    0.779560
1   -0.376945
2    0.980927
dtype: float64
```